# how to refer to a private class field in typescript jsdoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, hidden-field

Please tell me: how to refer to a private class field in typescript jsdoc?

script.js:

```js
// @ts-check

class C {

    /** @type { null | string | number } */
    #x = null;

    // /** @type { ( x : C[ 'x' ] ) => void } */
    // /** @type { ( x : this[ 'x' ] ) => void } */
    // /** @type { ( x : this[ '#x' ] ) => void } */
    // /** @type { ( x : this[ #x ] ) => void } */
    // /** @type { ( x : this#x ) => void } */
    // /** @type { ( x : this.#x ) => void } */
    // /** @type { ( x : this[ #'x' ] ) => void } */
    f( x ) { };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is an open issue in Typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47595) itself. But there is a workaround to get what you want.

```js
class C {
  #x: null | string | number = null;

  f = (() => {
    const privX = this.#x
    return (x: typeof privX) => {
    }
  })();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to use typedef to define a custom type once, then reference it in both places. Here I've used [@typedef](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#typedef-callback-and-param) to define MyType as `null | string | number`, then I've used that type for both the private class field #x and the function parameter.

```
// @ts-check

/** @typedef {null | string | number} MyType */

class C {
    /** @type {MyType} */
    #x = null;

    /** @type {(x: MyType) => void} */
    f(x) {
        console.log(this.#x)
    };
};
```